# Apache Camel - response after sending a message to a route

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm using `Apache Camel` and `Spring Boot` for my project. I have the following code where I receive a `json object` via `http` on the `rtos` endpoint; then I map it into a `POJO`, modify it and send it again to another endpoint.

```
restConfiguration().component("servlet").host("localhost").port("8080").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

rest("/request").post("/rtos").type(User.class).to("direct:rtos")

from("direct:rtos").process(new Processor() {

  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

      User body = exchange.getIn().getBody(User.class);
      System.out.println("Input object: " + body.getName() + ", " + body.getAge());
      body.setAge("35");
      System.out.println("Output object: " + body.getName() + ", " + body.getAge());
      }
  }).marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
    .to("http4://localhost:8080/receive?bridgeEndpoint=true");

from("servlet:/receive").unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, User.class).process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    User body = exchange.getIn().getBody(User.class);
    body.setAge("100");
    System.out.println("Received object: " + body.getName() + ", " + body.getAge());
    }
});
```

This works okay, meaning that the object is correctly manipulated and passed through the endpoints. What happens is that after sending the http request I get `500 Internal Server Error` and the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

I noticed that the error disappears if I manage to return something to the first route, for example

```
[...]
.to("http4://localhost:8080/receive?bridgeEndpoint=true").transform().constant("End of route");
```

I wonder why is that, and what it has to do with jackson serialization. And what if I don't want to send a reply to the first request? I red [this](http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html) and [this](http://camel.apache.org/event-message.html), and I tried to modify my code as follows:

```
from("direct:rtos").setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly).process(new Processor() {

            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                User body = exchange.getIn().getBody(User.class);
                System.out.println("Input object: " + body.getName() + ", " + body.getAge());

                body.setAge("35");
                System.out.println("Output object: " + body.getName() + ", " + body.getAge());


            }
        }).marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
                .inOnly("http4://localhost:8080/receive?bridgeEndpoint=true");
```

but I get the same error.
Can anyone suggest me where I'm wrong? I'm trying to understand properly how the Camel flow works, so it's possible that I've made some mistakes somewhere.
Thanks,
Sara

*EDIT* this is my User class:

```
package it.cam.resources;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable{

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("age")
    private String age;

    @JsonSerialize(using=StringSerializer.class)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonSerialize(using=StringSerializer.class)
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: who call `direct:rtos` ?

Comment: Can you post the "User.java" source, are you setting any jackson Serialization properties?

Comment: @JérémieB `direct:rtos` receives a json object via curl.
@blob I've updated the answer.

Comment: a `direct` component can't receive a message via http.

Comment: @JérémieB you're right, I'm sorry, I misspoke. I've updated my code with the complete call flow.

Comment: why are you bridging the endpoint? my guess is that there actually is an error before dispatching but the `bridgeEndpoint=true` forces camel to suppress the error

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether its already answered or not. I would suggest you to use [Stream Caching](http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html) after you receive the response. Which means, use `from("servlet:/receive").streamCaching()` in your route.

Comment: That does help indeed. I think this is because a stream from the response is being read several times or so, and as a result second time it's empty. This I think is due to the processor: that's the code that is reading the stream for the first time, and then after the processor it's empty. Same goes for logging.

I also had to either              set RestBindingMode.off, or convert .convertBodyTo(String::class.java) before unmarshalling command.